# Generating a random matrix with independent elements

Tags: matlab, random

Let's say R is a mxn random matrix. How can generate R with each entry of R is independent and identically chosen from any distribution with mean zero and variance mu^2?

Comment: What do you mean by `chosen from some unknown distribution'?

Comment: `m=10;n=5;mu=2;R=mu*randn(m,n);` will give you values from the normal distribution. See [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/stats/bq_w_hm.html#bq_w_ie-15) for other distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want 'randn', which chooses entries from a Gaussian distribution with norm 1. To get a variance of mu^2, use

```
mu*randn(m,n)
```

For instance:

```
x=10*randn(1,1e5);var(x)
```

I get:

```
ans =  
99.8547
```

Mileage may vary. =)